# Modify a variable passed to a generator function

Tags: python, parameter-passing, generator, pass-by-reference

I'm using a generator function to take some pictures from a camera. That function accepts a `quality` parameter, which I want to change dynamically if I detect that the size of the image is lower or greater than some value (to simplify). But this parameter is bound when I first call the generator, and I don't see a way to change it afterwards.

Sample code:

```
q = 30
for image in get_images('image_{$i}', quality=q):
    do_something_with(image)
    if len(image) < 1e6:
        q += 2
    elif len(image) > 1e7:
        q -= 2
```

I want to change that `q` variable, so the next times the generator function is executed in order to return a new image it uses the new value, instead of the one used at the moment it was (first) called.

The `get_images` function is inside a library, so I can't modify it to allow that `quality` parameter to be changed from outside. Its header is like this:

```
def get_images(output, format=None, resize=None, **options):
    ...
```

Given that header, I understand that the `quality` variable is inside the `options` object. I don't know if that is either good or bad for what I'm trying to do.

Is there a way to modify the variable inside that function, for example, by passing a reference to the value instead of the actual value to the function?

---

For clarification, the `get_images` is [`camera.capture_continuous`](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/api_camera.html#picamera.PiCamera.capture_continuous) function from `PiCamera`.

Comment: When you say, _"the next times the generator function is executed"_, do you mean the next time `get_images` is called, or the next time the generator object returned from `get_images` is advanced i.e. `next(gen_obj)`?

Comment: @ChristianDean I mean the next time the generator object returns another image.

Comment: I don't see the relevance of generator objects here.  It may be (we can't really tell from the question) that `get_images` is implemented as a generator but that's not realty the point.  The point is that you have already got the image so it's too late to change the quality.  You'll probably need to get it again to have it with a different quality.  Or you'll need to write a quality changing function yourself.

Comment: "The get_images function is inside a library, so I can't modify it to allow that quality parameter to be changed from outside" - well, that pretty much eliminates all options that don't involve reimplementing (some part of) get_images.

Comment: @strubbly Once I got an image I'm not trying to change its quality, but the quality for the next one to be taken. The function `get_images` is a generator for sure, I don't know if it's relevant or not.

Comment: @user2357112 I was thinking about passing a reference to the variable. I haven't coded using python so much, so I don't know if that is even possible.

Comment: @IvánPérez: Not possible, and even if it was possible, it'd probably just break things, since the code wasn't written with the expectation that someone could change that value.

Comment: Looking a bit at the source code, I don't see a normal way. The quality gets passed to the encoder, which you could try to access with `inspect.getgeneratorlocals`, maybe the encoder lets you change its settings. Other than that, *maybe* the quality value somehow gets operated on in a way so that you could provide not an int but an instance of a subclass of int that you write which would provide the updated quality at that operation. I'm not equipped to test. What happens when you try `quality=object()`? Maybe you're lucky and that will error with some useful message.